# LWJGL GLSL 3D Lighting

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

I am currently trying to learn about lighting with GLSL using LWJGL, more specifically I would like to learn how to create different kinds of lights for both per vertex and per pixel. However the closest I have got in finding a tutorial with everything I want to know has been [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/lighting/). The only problem is that it doesn't really specify how I would be able implement this properly. I wondered if anyone else knew of any tutorials specific to LWJGL which would have things such as directional lights, point lights etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding an OpenGL tutorial for LWJGL specifically is almost impossible.  At least I haven't found one yet.  However, since LWJGL is almost a direct port of all the OpenGL methods anyways, most OpenGL tutorials will do.  You just have to be able to convert the C OpenGL code to Java LWJGL code.  It becomes trivial after a while.

And on that note, I've found this OpenGL tutorial really helpful.  It has a lot of sample code too.

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

It also has a section on basic lighting similar to the tutorial you linked.  This tutorial has a bunch of sample GLSL code though that you can hack around with.

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/